# Library to use css rules to style a NSView

Tags: css, cocoa, nsview

Is there a way to style NSViews using css like rules? So that you don't have to use drawings commands? is there a library for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. You'll need to use Quartz (the native drawing facilities) or a third-party drawing library. Alternatively, you could use a WebView.

Comment: yes, I meant, is there a library to do css like styling of a nsview?

Comment: Yes, and I answered that in my first one-word sentence. ;-)